# How to pause my animation in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I am trying to animate a background image, I wanted to know what is the best practice for adding a pause feature inside this function?

```
function scrollBg(){
    //Go to next pixel row.
    current -= step;

    //If at the end of the image, then go to the top.
    if (current == restartPosition){
        current = 0;
    }

    //Set the CSS of the header.
    $('#campaignid').css("background-position","0 "+current+"px");
}

//Calls the scrolling function repeatedly
var init = setInterval("scrollBg()", scrollSpeed);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `clearInterval(init)` to stop the animation, then remember current step in some variable and start animation from this step when needed by setInterval. Alternatively you can have another global variable (similar to current), which will indicate whether you can execute body of scrollBg or not, for example:

```
function scrollBg(){
    if(isPause){
      return;
    }
    //Go to next pixel row.
    current -= step;

    //If at the end of the image, then go to the top.
    if (current == restartPosition){
        current = 0;
    }

//Set the CSS of the header.
$('#campaignid').css("background-position","0 "+current+"px");
```

}

You'll set pause by setting `isPause = true`

Comment: +1 - you beat me to this answer only because IE crashed a couple of minutes ago when I tried to post my equivalent version. I definitely prefer the "isPaused" approach in 90% of cases; I find clearing and restarting the intervals too fiddly (though obviously it can work just as well).

Comment: Using `clearInterval` is definitely preferable. Using the `isPause` variable and leaving the interval active will waste CPU cycles doing nothing, and (very slightly) hurt client-side performance for no reason.

Comment: @Tobias Cohen, it depends on the duration of pause and intervals between animation frames. At some cases `isPause` could be more effective. But in general, you're right.

Comment: @Tobias - if the page only uses one or two intervals the performance hit of `isPaused` is going to be so small you couldn't measure it, especially if the interval is relatively long. (And if it's using more than one or two intervals I'd suggest there might be something wrong with the design.)

Answer (score 0):

How about you use clearInterval at a certain value of current (i.e. clearInterval(init)), and reset the interval at another time?